# PHP POST File Upload not working.. can't figure out what's wrong?

Tags: php, android, ios

I am building an App and want users to be able to pin photos to a website from their smartphones. Currently the code is working from iPhone, but I cannot get it to work from Android for some reason, even though with a post test server (http://www.posttestserver.com) it works flawlessly!

I just cannot figure out what might be wrong at this point.

This is my code:

```
<?php
include_once('db.php');
include_once('hfk_utils.php');


if ($_POST) {
  if ($_FILES['imgfile']['error'] == 0) {
      $filepath = UPLOAD_PATH.$_FILES['imgfile']['name'];
      $uri = UPLOAD_URI_PATH.$_FILES['imgfile']['name'];
      $url = URL_BASE_TRUE . '/' . $uri;
      $thumb = URL_BASE_TRUE . '/' . UPLOAD_URI_PATH. 'thumbs/' . $_FILES['imgfile'] ['name'];
      $timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imgfile']['tmp_name'],$filepath);
      createThumbs( UPLOAD_PATH, UPLOAD_THUMB_PATH, 100 );
      $sql = mysql_query('INSERT INTO hfk_images (rid,uri,url,thumbnail) VALUES ("'.$_POST['rid'].'","'.$uri.'","'.$url.'","'.$thumb.'")');
      $iid = mysql_insert_id();
      mysql_query('INSERT INTO hfk_nodes (rid,author,text,iid,timestamp) VALUES ("'.$_POST['rid'].'","'.$_POST['author'].'","'.$_POST['title'].'","'.$iid.'","'.$timestamp.    '")');
  } else {
    print_r($_FILES);
    print 'Cant Upload Image';
  }
} else {
    print 'Cant Upload Image';
}

die();
?>
```

Thanks for all help!

Comment: You could try posting identical data from iPhone and android and then check for differences on posttestserver

Comment: what error or response it shows ?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have `enctype='multiform/data'` set up on the form